# pyqt : Why QGLWidget influenced by maya event?

Tags: opengl, maya, qglwidget

[openGL with maya](http://vimeo.com/53142579)

I made a openGL View with QGLWidget. It has a problem when work with Maya. As you see in video, when I click and move on a modelPanel within Maya, the QGLWidget get broken. And I found that the marquee rectangle is shown on my QGLWidget, not Maya. Why this problem happend?

## To datenwolf

I tried to edit my code as you suggested. But... it doesn't call makeCurrent() and doneCurrent() at all. I expected that when I clicked on my maya modelPanel it could send me the message, but it didn't. What did I miss? Sorry for that.

```
def makeCurrent(self):
    import OpenGL.WGL as wgl
    print "MAKE CURRENT!!!"
    self.prevHDC = wgl.wglGetCurrentDC()
    self.prevHRC = wgl.wglGetCurretnContext()
    super(GLWidget, self).makeCurrent()
        
def doneCurrent(self):
    import OpenGL.WGL as wgl
    print "DONE CURRENT!!!"
    super(GLWidget, self).doneCurrent()
    wgl.wglMakeCurrent(self.prevHDC, self.prevHRC)
```

I wrote just like above. But it never even show the "MESSAGE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Qt and Maya's event loop are battling for processing event. Qt's paintGL does the right thing and makes the OpenGL context current whenever it is called. Maya however does not and so drawing commands of Maya end up in your OpenGL context.

Playing along with Maya is going to be tricky, because it requires storing which OpenGL/DC context was active before switching and restoring that once finished with one own's operations. You'll probably have to subclass QGLWidget and QGLContext to do this.

## Update due to comment

Derive from QGLWidget, add two members `HDC m_prevHDC` and `HRC m_prevHRC`, override makeCurrent and doneCurrent

```
void QMyGLWidget::makeCurrent()
{
    this->m_prevHDC = wglGetCurrentDC();
    this->m_prevHRC = wglGetCurrentContext();

    QGLWidget::makeCurrent();
}

void QMyGLWidget::doneCurrent()
{
     QGLWidget::doneCurrent();

     wglMakeCurrent(this->m_prevHDC, this->m_prevHRC);
}
```

Then derive your actual GLWidget from this intermediary class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I can't understand the your answer. First of all, I don't know abut QGLContext :( and you mean that I have to use single-bufer and swap?

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim: No, what I mean is, that somewhere in Qt's code there's a line wglMakeCurrent, making the QGLWidgets OpenGL context receive all OpenGL calls. Maya has a similar line. The problem is, Maya doesn't call it all the time. So your program must revert its context binding, i.e. clean up behind itself. This is done by mirroring the wglMakeCurrent call for your GL context with a wglMakeCurrent call to Maya's GL context. wglGetCurrentContext can be used to retrieve that. Since context binding happens "behind the scenes" of QGLWidget and QGLContext you'll have to subclass them to add this.

Comment: At last, I got your advice. I tried like that in my timer related method.
`self.makeCurrent()`
`self.updateGL()`
`self.doneCurrent()`
But, with this code, Maya loose it's own GL works. (I can't draw marquee on Maya modelPanel :( ) Surely I'm poor at OpenGL

Comment: Would you do me a favor? Could you write a breif pseudo code for me? I can't find the flow.

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim: See my code update. Essentially you must create sort of a transaction rollback mechanism.